# Lock record in table while reading from another table

Tags: mysql, locking

I am using this command and it works fine for me.

```
update inventory set st1avq1=
(SELECT sum(total) FROM 
(SELECT SUM(quant*acc)total FROM reportscenter WHERE PID=1 and fromstore=1 
union all 
SELECT SUM(quant) total FROM reportscenter WHERE PID=1 and tostore=1)
a)
,totalquant=st1avq1 ,requestdbrepair=0 WHERE ID=1;
```

I am updating a record in `inventory` table from `reportscenter` table

what I want is to lock that record in the same last command so no one else can read or write from that record ... something like

```
lock tables inventory where ID=1
```

Comment: but your query seems to update the products table not inventory table

Comment: sorry .. yes I crorrected it

Comment: What sense does it make to prevent reads?  Because the value is being modified?  My sql+spidey sense tells me this requirement is to cover up bad behavior elsewhere... such as not using `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` somewhere else (which would have given you the desired effect automatically, since this update transaction would have an X lock on the row in question, blocking the IX lock from the other transaction) that can end up writing the wrong value back to the row.  Explain?